# angular section option, new div should load when any option is selected

Tags: javascript, angular, dropdown, html-select

I want to select any option from the doctors name,
and whatever name is clicked, then the div should load. new div should load for each option selected.

```
 <select 
    class="docName" 
    [(ngModel)]="selectedID" 
    (ngModelChange)="doctorId($event)">
    <option disabled> Select Doctor</option>
    <option 
        *ngFor="let name of doctor" 
        id="{{ name.user_id }}" 
        [ngValue]="name">
        {{ name.doctor_name }}
    </option>
</select>

<div>show this data</div>
```

TScode, for displaying doctor name:

```
doctorId(doctor_Id) {
    this.delete = false;
    if (doctor_Id === "All") {
      this.doctorID = doctor_Id;

    } else {
      this.doctorID = doctor_Id.user_id;

    }
```

Comment: Which div are you referring to? What should it display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use *ngIf from the CommonModule. Always try to keep it simple.
Example:

```
<div *ngIf="doctorID">{{doctorID}}</div> // Display what ever you want after a selection was mage
```

Set your doctorID to `undefined` or `null` when no doctor is selected.